# What is the acceleration of light (photon) in vacuum?

Tags: special-relativity, photons, acceleration, speed-of-light, refraction

We all know that the speed of light is 299792458m/s, but what is the acceleration of photons? That is to say, does the photon have a speed transition from zero to the speed of light?

Comment: Photons are born going the speed of light.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Light has no acceleration. It always travels at C